# vim repeat a pattern in a replace command

Tags: regex, vim, macvim, neovim

I have the following text:

```
Lang1
Lang2
Lang3
```

Now I want to replace all the text in each line with a pattern like:

```
{ DisplayName: DispName(Lang1), Value: Lang1 },
{ DisplayName: DispName(Lang1), Value: Lang2 },
{ DisplayName: DispName(Lang1), Value: Lang3 },
```

Now how do I achieve this with the vim command substitution, I can get: `:%s/*$/\{\ DisplayName\:\ DispName\(Lang1\)\,\ Value\:\ Lang1\}\,/` to replace each line with `Lang1` and then replace the individual 1s with 2, 3, 4, etc. But I do not want to do that. I want a single substitute command to select the pattern and repeat it. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
:%s/.*/{ DisplayName: DispName(&), Value: &},/
```

Here `&` is back-reference of complete matched string using `.*`. This will replace given content with this content:

```
{ DisplayName: DispName(Lang1), Value: Lang1},
{ DisplayName: DispName(Lang2), Value: Lang2},
{ DisplayName: DispName(Lang3), Value: Lang3},
```

If you want to be more specific then you may use this regex instead of `.*`:

```
^Lang[0-9]*$
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I know that we could repeat the pattern but could not find it from google. "&" and "back-reference" were the terms that I were missing in my google query.